# Flutter Exception : The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture: The getter 'email' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Flutter is showing me that my loggedInUser is empty/void. But i saved it's value from user in getCurrentUser() method . Now due to that, my code is getting an exception at line 92(The line, which is followed by a comment). The exception is -

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The getter 'email' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: email

//But whenever i use  _auth.currentUser.email in place of loggedInUser, my code runs fine. I don't understand why??

Please someone help me out, I am new to flutter.

Here's my code for chatting screen -

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:palabrero_chat_app/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const String id = 'chat_screen';

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {

  final myController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
  String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Firebase.initializeApp().whenComplete(() {
      print("completed");
      setState(() {});
    });
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if(user!=null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
                //Implement logout functionality
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      getCurrentUser();
                      //messageText + loggedInUser.email
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text' : messageText,
                        'sender' :  loggedInUser.email,   //This line no. 92
                         //If i use  _auth.currentUser.email above, in place of loggedInUser, my code 
                         works. Please explain it to me.
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Comment: which version of firebase_auth are you using?

Comment: @PeterHaddad 0.18.0+1

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if(user!=null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

into this:

```
  void getCurrentUser()  {
    try {
      final user  = _auth.currentUser;
      if(user!= null) {
        setState(() { loggedInUser = user; });
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Remove async/await since `currentUser` does not return a `Future`, also use `setState` to update the variable `loggedInUser`

Answer (score 0):

As Peter said .. I followed his approach but my code worked while I did following:

1. I removed async/await and added setState but failed - it was saying I cant assign a Future to user as loggedInUser was a FirebaseUser.
2. I readded async/await and kept setState as it is & the code worked..

So I feel, it is just for a FirebaseUser, we need to add setState to the loggedInUser assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In function
`getCurrentUser()` try to change `final user  = _auth.currentUser;`

to `final user  = _auth.currentUser();`
just add those parenthesis.